# How do I hide or remove warnings for a specific pod dependency?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, firebase-remote-config

I am using the `Firebase/Remote` config pod and that pod depends on a pod called `Protobuf`
Which has a lot of warnings.
My pod file

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'AppeeUITests' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '4.4'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.4'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

end

target 'AppeeUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
end

target 'AppeeUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
end
```

Here are the warnings that it yields: 
[image]

Comment: Simply update your pods.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani sorry, I am new to iOS. How do I do that?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I did a `pod update` it did not work

Comment: Which version are u using in the 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

Comment: no specific version. Please see my pod file in the question

Comment: When you are run pod install the console will show the version of all pods

Comment: I am using `FirebaseRemoteConfig (2.0.0)` and `Protobuf (3.3.0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146493/discussion-between-salman-ghumsani-and-archlucifer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't worry for the warnings if you are using `FirebaseRemoteConfig (2.0.0)` and `Protobuf (3.3.0)` version. This is already updated and you are using the latest release, so you have to wait for the next release from Google firebase for removing the warning, it means that Firebase team have to work for the updations.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be solved by updating your pod.

Steps to update the pod:
1. open terminal and come to your project directory
2. run 'pod update' command

It'll update your all pods framework.

If you received pod command not found then try using 'sudo gem install cocoapods' or [follow these steps simply](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).